# Can you copy a MySQL database without a front-end software involved?

Tags: mysql, wamp, citrus-engine

I was told that you cannot copy a MySQL database without using the front-end software (in this case Citrus Savings and Loans) that was built along with it.

A brief history: A certain IT company created a front-end software and used a free version of MySQL as its database. Of course they set up a root password for it. Now they do not want to cooperate by migrating it to our new server or at least give us the root password to copy the database.

My question is this: Is the root password exclusive to the front-end software or is it just the MySQL root password? Also, since the IT company doesn't wanna help, is there a way to copy the old MySQL database without the root password nor the Citrus Savings and Loans front-end software and save it to our new server?

NOTE: I just found out that the IT company used WAMP as the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone can copy a MySQL database if you have access to the filesystem. Without direct access to the filesystem, youcan still create MySQL dumps if you have a mysql username with at least read access.